# Why does os.path.exists() stop windows named pipes from connecting?

Tags: python, windows, named-pipes, pywin32, python-3.7

It seems that a successful test of the existence of a windows named pipe by using `os.path.exists()` prevents the pipe from working. Why would this be?

Here is successfully working windows named-pipe code:

```
import time
import multiprocessing as mp
import win32pipe, win32file

PIPENAME = r'\\.\pipe\Foo'

def producer(pipe_name: str):
    print('producer')
#    if not os.path.exists(pipe_name):
#        print(f'No pipe {pipe_name}')
#        return
    pipe = win32file.CreateFile(pipe_name,
                                win32file.GENERIC_READ | win32file.GENERIC_WRITE,  # dwDesiredAccess
                                0,  # dwShareMode
                                None,  # lpSecurityAttributes
                                win32file.OPEN_EXISTING,  # dwCreationDisposition
                                0,  # dwFlagsAndAttributes
                                None
                                )
    win32pipe.SetNamedPipeHandleState(pipe, win32pipe.PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE, None, None)
    win32file.WriteFile(pipe, b'foobar')


def receiver(pipe_name: str):
    print('receiver')
    pipe = win32pipe.CreateNamedPipe(pipe_name,
                                     win32pipe.PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
                                     win32pipe.PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE | win32pipe.PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE | win32pipe.PIPE_WAIT,
                                     1,  # nMaxInstances
                                     65536,  # nOutBufferSize
                                     65536,  # nInBufferSize
                                     0, # 50ms timeout (the default)
                                     None) # securityAttributes
    win32pipe.ConnectNamedPipe(pipe)
    msg = win32file.ReadFile(pipe, 65536)
    print(f'msg: {msg}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    recv_p = mp.Process(target=receiver, args=(PIPENAME,))
    prod_p = mp.Process(target=producer, args=(PIPENAME,))
    recv_p.start()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    prod_p.start()
    prod_p.join()
    recv_p.join()
```

This works as expected, with the receiver printing the received message.

But if the three commented-out lines in the producer are uncommented, the `os.path.exists(pipe_name)` call somehow breaks the pipe so the output becomes:

```
receiver
producer
Process Process-2:
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\redacted\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\redacted\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\git\redacted\named_pipe_mqtt_test.py", line 18, in producer
    None
pywintypes.error: (231, 'CreateFile', 'All pipe instances are busy.')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\redacted\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\redacted\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\git\redacted\named_pipe_mqtt_test.py", line 35, in receiver
    msg = win32file.ReadFile(pipe, 65536)
pywintypes.error: (109, 'ReadFile', 'The pipe has been ended.')
```

Why would `os.path.exists` break windows named pipes?

I've ruled out the python multiprocessing library. I've tried a delay after `os.path.exists`.

This is not a blocking problem for me, but I am curious.

Comment: Can you try to narrow it down to exactly what causes the problem? First, I'm pretty sure `os.path.exists` just calls `os.stat`, but check that. Then, that must be calling `CreateFileW(FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES)`, so check whether doing that and then closing the handle breaks things. Then… there are a few different things it might be calling on that handle, so you probably have to look inside `posixmodule.c` to see if it's calling `GetFileInformationByHandle` or something else, but whatever it is, see if calling that breaks things. And so on.

Comment: `os.stat` does call `CreateFileW`, query some info (which fails since the named-pipe file system only supports a very limited set of queries),  and `CloseHandle`. The pipe is now in the closing state, and the server side should detect the error and call `DisconnectNamedPipe` to allow a new connection.

Comment: Also causing the same problem are the calls  `FindFirstFileNameW` and `GetFileAttributes`. But this works: I can do `os.listdir(r'\\.\pipe')` and check for the existence of the pipe name. It seems odd that there's no other non-destructive way of checking for the existence of a named pipe.

Comment: In the Windows API, use `FindFirstFile[Ex]` with the name of the pipe, e.g. `"\\\\?\\pipe\\Foo"`. This is implemented in NT by opening `"\\\\?\\pipe\\"` (the NPFS root directory) via `NtOpenFile`, and querying for the `FileName` "Foo" via `NtQueryDirectyoryFile[Ex]`. If it's not found `FindFirstFile[Ex]` returns `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`. Otherwise close the find handle via `FindClose`.  If the name is found, NPFS sets the file 'size' (`nFileSizeLow`) as the number of instances open when queried.

Comment: Note that `os.listdir(r'\\?\pipe')` is similar, but it queries for `"*.*"` to list all named pipes, which isn't as efficient is asking NPFS to check for exactly one name.

Comment: With PyWin32 you can use `win32api.FindFiles(r'\\?\pipe\Foo')`. As noted, this returns the current number of instances as the file size. If you want the maximum number of instances allowed, use a query that also returns the *allocation* size, such as `GetFileInformationByHandleEx` : `FileFullDirectoryInfo` (supported by NPFS, an available in Windows 8+). In their infinite 'wisdom', they provide no way to pass a `FileName` wildcard filter with this function. That's only available via NTAPI `NtQueryDirectoryFile` : `FileFullDirectoryInformation`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.path.exists` delegates to `os.stat`, and on Windows, `os.stat` tries to [*open*](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.4/Modules/posixmodule.c#L1826) the file:

```c
hFile = CreateFileW(path, access, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, flags, NULL);
```

Then it closes the file. At this point, the client can't reopen the pipe unless the server side first calls [`DisconnectNamedPipe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/namedpipeapi/nf-namedpipeapi-disconnectnamedpipe), which doesn't happen in this code. Also, when the server side tries to read from the pipe, it's reading from `os.stat`'s connection attempt, which closed the pipe without writing any data.

I would consider this a bug. `os.stat` should not have such side effects.