# Trying to open an existing named pipe in Windows 10 - errno 22, Invalid Argument, but why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pipe, ipc, named-pipes

I'm writing/experimenting with a python script that needs to connect to an existing named pipe in Windows 10. I'm using Python 3.8.

#### The Named Pipe

Specifically, I'm trying to connect to a pipe named `SendPipe1` and write 14 ascii-encoded characters to it.

The pipe was created by some other software (driver?) for a device connected to my PC. I am connecting to it to try to interact with the device in the same way the manufacturer-provided software does. The manufacturer-provided software connects to this same pipe and sends a coded message to it, which commands the device to do something. This is what I'd like to do.

I know the pipe already exists from running the PipeList utility:

```
PipeList v1.02 - Lists open named pipes
Copyright (C) 2005-2016 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Pipe Name                                    Instances       Max Instances
---------                                    ---------       -------------
[...]
chrome.blah.foo                                   1                1
SendPipe1                                         1               -1
ReceivePipe1                                      1               -1
chrome.blah.bar                                   1                1
[...]
```

#### The Code

Here is what I have right now:

```
ACTIVE_DISP_ID = 1
msg = f'6;16;100;{ACTIVE_DISP_ID};1\r\n'
pipe_path = f'\\\\.\\PIPE\\SendPipe{ACTIVE_DISP_ID}'

try:
    f = open(pipe_path, 'wb+', buffering=0)
    f.write(msg.encode(encoding='ascii'))
except OSError as e:
    raise
```

which gives me

#### The Error(s)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Spooqi/PycharmProjects/Spooqi/radiant/pipe-test.py", line 7, in <module>
    f = open(pipe_path, 'wb+', buffering=0)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '\\\\.\\PIPE\\SendPipe1'
```

I am fairly certain the path `'\\\\.\\PIPE\\SendPipe1'` is correct, because if I change it to something like `'\\\\.\\PIPE\\FooPipeBar'`, I get a different Exception:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\\\\.\\PIPE\\FooPipeBar'
```

and if I write to a regular file that doesn't (yet) exist with relative path `foobar` it will just produce a text file with that message normally.

#### The Question(s)

In this context, what does errno 22 mean? Why is this argument invalid? Why can't I connect to this pipe and write to it?

Is there some other process already connected to the pipe? How would I check that? If there is, how can I also connect to the device with a pipe at the same time?

Comment: I have also tried starting PyCharm (my IDE) with Admin privileges. Is there anyone who can offer some guidance?

Comment: i have this error after `os.path.exists` call https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51255352

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a source for this, but errno 22 when opening a pipe on Windows from Python seems to indicates the pipe is already in use by another process.

For instance:

- Hyper-V opens `\\.\pipe\pipe1` for writing as a ComPort for VM-A
- Hyper-V can't also open `\\.\pipe\pipe1` for writing as a ComPort for VM-B

or:

- Hyper-V opens a ComPort `\\.\pipe\pipe1` for writing
- Program-A opens ComPort `\\.\pipe\pipe1` for reading
- Program-B can't also open `\\.\pipe\pipe1` for reading

There are probably additional caveats based on the type of pipe, but this has been my observations for Error 22 when using single reader/writer named pipes with Hyper-V

When using Powershell, you see this error

```
PS C:\> $pipe = new-object System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeClientStream \\.\pipe\pipe1
PS C:\> $pipe.Connect(1)
Exception calling "Connect" with "1" argument(s): "The semaphore timeout period has expired.
"
At line:1 char:1
+ $pipe.Connect(1)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : IOException
```